Etymology - Specifically for medical science and/or adjacent studies
I absolutely love recommending the study resource "Etymonline" to students seeking to build their vocabularies in topics with very old and eclectic dictionaries, like medicine.
However, the only drawback to Etymonline is that it is not subject specific. As such, it lacks a certain level of technical detail and term library comprehensiveness.
I am trying to find similar resources to direct students to, but I am stumped. Even some of the highly regarded medical books on etymology still focus primarily on one defining feature of the word's history, but they lack true etymological entries. I can't blame them, hard to be both a physician and etymologist, I guess one had to take a bit of a backseat.
So, how can I get the best of both fields: Medicine & Etymology? I'd very much like to have my cake and eat it as well. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Are you perhaps looking for an Encyclopedia? Or perhaps just any or all of Google, Chargpt, and Wikipedia.

@FumbleFingers - Great suggestions. However, I think you are underestimating the challenge that these terms pose. Medical science terminology is needlessly difficult to access when searching for a high degree of technical accuracy. Even the most prestigious textbooks don't present much etymology, let alone a comprehensive collection. The last thing I want is for these medical students to be directly learning from Wiki & ChatGPT. Good tools, but lacking in accurate detail and trustworthiness. Be my guest, Dr. Google, Wiki and GPT will see you now. I'm so sorry, its terminal spaghetti nipples.

Wikipedia is normally very accurate for these things. And nobody is suggesting using it for medical treatment, just etymology so your snark seems a bit misplaced. You could also try the OED and databases on the history of medicine. Or encourage students to do their own research.

Medical Etymology: https://metymology.ch/

Can you give an example of a term whose etymology as found at Etymonline (or the OED, on which it mainly draws) is lacking for your medical purposes? Also, what age are your students? Do they have institutional access to medical databases?

Ignoring basics like 'arm' and 'liver', the analysis of most technical medical terms, like 'epithelium' is transparent... -if- you know Greek and Latin. They are for the most part constructed by individuals doing research (in Europe since 1400s, so the terms are pan-European). As to the date and individual, the OED often has a first appearance, but not always and the OED is mostly paywalled. Etymology of epithelium
